# Is there possibility to create app using GUI and 3D Graphics libraries simultaneously?

Tags: c++, qt, unity-game-engine, render, blender

Is there possibility to obtain 3d graphics quality like from blender or unity3D in qt/juce/gtk+ gui app?

Comment: Yes, the only limit is your skill and imagination. Naturally, good quality graphics comes at the expense of thousands of work hours.

Answer (score 1):

Many GUI libraries (for example, Qt) have integration with OpenGL. Spicifically, you can create an OpenGL widget (which comes with an OpenGL context) and render in it via OpenGL.

This doesn't automatically mean you have Blender or Unity 3D quality, of course; you'll have to do the graphics.

Comment: I know either OpenGL,DirectX or Vulkan. Actually, I've worked a bit with qt and opengl but obtained 3d model was very poor. I don't want to reinvent wheel with opengl.Therefore i'm looking for other possibility, some at higher level of abstraction.
I don't want write a game, rather app for 3D data processing where i need real time preview.

Comment: @Remigiusz Well, 3D data visualization is even a better use case for OpenGL, from my point of view. This means you don't need neat graphics, just render some points, lines, triangles, with simple shaders. This is relatively simple with OpenGL or alternatives, and you save youself from verbosity and heaviness of mature rendering engines.

Comment: On the one hand you're right but on the other hand i would like to see neat graphics instead graphics from doom 2. 
Yes, i don't need to super complex textures and super realistic appearance of rendered objects. I don't expect visual effect as from new unreal engine 4, but just neat graphic. 
With opengl, directx, vulkan libraries it will be relatively hard.

Comment: @Remigiusz Well, at this point the world "relatively" has relative meaning itself :) I personally have used OpenGL for similar tasks, and with a bit of experience it becomes quite easy and flexible. Neat graphics can mean a load of different things; for data visualization it usually does not need that much work. That being said, a mature ready-to-use solution would definitely be better, but I'm not aware of any in existence. Btw, probably you should add more info about your specific use case into the question; it currently seems to address something not that relevant.

Comment: @Remigiusz By the way, making something look like Doom 2 nowadays is harder then not doing it, since the hardware & rendering api made a large step since those days.

Comment: Thx for help, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

It is possible of course. Check out **OpenGL and DirectX**

If you are into game developing then it all depends on what you want to do. If you want the engine to be specialized specifically for your game, then do so. If you want to save yourself quite a bit of work, then use a premodern engine.

This is where you could start with OpenGL https://open.gl/introduction

Also you should consider that there is a new API called **Vulkan**

> Vulkan is intended to provide a variety of advantages over other APIs
>   as well as its spiritual predecessor, OpenGL. Vulkan offers lower
>   overhead, more direct control over the GPU, and lower CPU usage.[12]
>   The overall concept and feature set of Vulkan is similar to Direct3D
>   12 and Mantle.

**But Vulkan is much harder to master from 0 to hero, so you should go learn OpenGL first or something easier.**

Comment: +1 mentioning Vulkan, as well as that it's harder. I'd also like to mention that OpenGL 2.1 is a good start for a novice, and is worth learning before modern OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, GL3.3+ has introduced much nicer (and more performant) ways of handling many things, you'll be making better use of the player's hardware (and they'll be grateful to you for that) and you'll be spending more time writing productive code rather than fighting an API that really doesn't want to co-operate with you.